Luggage Specifications: Dimension vs Weight
All the airlines specify luggage dimension as well as weight. However from what I have seen, most of the the focus is on weight only. I have never seen dimensions being measured.
I am in a situation where airline allows One check-in luggage and One Hand Luggage. I will be having One big luggage for check-in which will have less weight but will meet dimension criteria, same for my Hand luggage; Along with this I will be having a small backpack. If airlines objects to having one hand luggage + one backpack (I have seen Emirates being strict with this) then I plan to check-in my hand luggage as well and keep backpack with me.
But given that my check-in luggage already meets dimension criteria, I am wondering if airlines will charge me for additional luggage even if total weight is within limits.
Edit:
Just want to add more info. If we look at the "other permitted items" section for hand baggage, it mentions a shoulder bag with specification 40 * 30 * 10 cm
So per rules hand luggage can be more than one but in case of space crunch airline may apply discretion.
Edit2:
Adding more clarity to the question. I have one hand luggage and one Check-in luggage both within specifications. I generally carry an additional small bag with my tab. However this time I have a DSLR with multiple lenses, so I have brought a bag to carry all electronic items together : https://www.amazon.in/dp/B07GVL4R7L?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_fed_asin_title
I referring to this bag as backpack. It is the look of this bag which concerns me.

What airline are you flying with, on what itinerary, and what fare?

Its SwissAir , Economy fair

Classic/Flex Economy, or Economy light? What route?

Flex Economy, Delhi-Zurich

If I understand correctly, you're wondering if, in the case where the airline forces you to check-in a second piece of luggage, they would charge you for it, given that your fare only include a single piece of checked luggage?

(+1) You may want to clarify your question. You are indeed allowed two pieces of hand luggage, the backpack being one of them. Writing “one hand luggage plus one bag pack” seemed to have generated an endless amount of confusion and controversy. Now, if all your hand luggage fits within the rules you have nothing to fear: even if the airline asks or forces you to check them in, it will be free of charge. Is that what you were unsure about? Or are you wondering what would happen if you show up with bags that are larger than allowed?

Note that in practice how your main piece of hand luggage looks like also matters: hard shell rolling suitcases just seem to attract more scrutiny than soft bags of the same size. A woman's purse, laptop bag, or small duffle is also more likely to get a pass as a personal item than a hiking backpack.

Thanks @Relaxed for all inputs. I have added more specific details to my query.

This “handbag, laptop bag or shoulder bag (max. 40 x 30 x 10 cm)” is just another example of “personal item”. That's the second piece of hand luggage that's allowed in Economy. Your back pack does not fit this definition.

The Amazon listing does not give the actual bag size (it only gives the size of the package it is delivered in) but it seems to exceed the size for the “second item” by far. Actually, if its size is anywhere close to the package size, it even exceeds the maximum allowed for the “main” carry-on item. You will have to check it in, at a cost.

If you already have the backpack, it’s pretty simple, take a tape measure and check its dimensions by yourself…

@jcaron It seems to be the actual bag size, you can check the brand's own website, which quotes the same dimensions in inches. Good tip on double checking that if you have the bag.

Rules vary a lot with airline AND the specific ticket and fare class. You need check the exact rules for your specific airline and ticket. There is no general answer to your question.
Dimensions apply to each single checked item individually. However, most airlines restrict the number of items (aka "count") you can check. I.e. if you have allowance for one checked bag and you try to check a second one, you will have to pay extra regardless of size and weight. The fees are often substantial.
I have seen pretty any possible combination for your case: some airlines go by total weight (regardless of count), some go by count (number of pieces checked) and weight, some allow carry on plus "personal item", some allow only one item in the cabin, etc.
Dimensions of checked luggage are typically generous and rarely a problem (unless you have something odd shaped or very bulky) but again it can be based on max value for each dimensions, sum of dimensions or any combination thereof.
Dimensions for carry-on bags are more important and many airline have a "sizer" at the gate. If your bag doesn't fit into the sizer, you can't carry it on.
For a while some airlines (specifically Lufthansa group) were weighing carry-on bags too, but they seemed to have eased up on that.

If an airline mentions one carry on item and they enforce that, checking in your other carry on item will be at the high airport rates. Better to pack so you only have one carry on, even a small handbag often counts as a carry on item, a backpack regardless the size also.

Travelers I have seen stuff the pockets of their coat or outdoor jacket in order to bypass the regulations. Some  outer garmets can have an amazing amount of pockets. Once the plane has boarded they move the stuff to a folded carry bag.

The rules also vary with the origin/destination countries, even for a single airline.

Swiss hand baggage rules allow (in economy):

1 item, max weight 8 kg, max dimensions 55 x 40 x 23 cm
and 1 handbag, laptop bag or shoulder bag, max dimensions 40 x 30 x 10 cm

You should expect them to enforce the rules, especially on shorter flights with narrow body (single aisle) aircraft where cabin space is limited, even more so if the flight is very busy or in cold weather (people have a lot more stuff to stow in the overhead bins).
Note that in some cases they may put your carry-on item in the hold at the gate (if the flight is full / they are out of space) but there's no extra cost for this as long as you are within the allowance.
If however you exceed the allowance (more than these two items, or exceeding the dimensions), you will have to pay extra to have it put in the hold, and that can be quite expensive.
Note that max dimensions are all inclusive: wheels, handles, pockets, etc. are counted. They usually have sizers for both sizes at the gate, and gate staff are quite quick to detect anything that may go over the limit. If it doesn't fit in the sizer (even by 1 cm), you will have to check it at the gate and there will be an extra cost.
Checked baggage rules depend on the actual fare

If you have an "Economy Light" fare, no checked luggage is included
In "Classic" and "Flex" Economy fares, you are allowed 1 single piece of luggage of 23 kg max. It must not exceed 158 cm (width + height + depth).

If you want to check more than item (or any item at all on a "Light" fare), you'll have to pay extra. It is usually cheaper to do so in advance rather than at the airport.
Update based on additional data
The backpack you are considering is way larger than the maximum allowed size for the "personal item" (the second item). While the Amazon listing only gives the "package size" (61 x 46.6 x 27 cm) rather than the size of the backpack itself, the two are probably quite close, and judging from the pictures, there's no dimension below 10 cm in any case.
So, no, this does not fit within your allowance. It's possible it may not be noticed, but you definitely can't count on it, and if they consider it to be too big and it needs to be checked at the gate, it will cost you quite a bit more than the (already expensive) fee when you pay for it online in advance.
You will need to either repack so you do indeed have only one carry-on and one checked bag (both within their respective maximum sizes/weights), or will have to pay for an extra checked bag.
For reference, on a Mumbai-Zurich flight in Economy, an additional checked bag is €160-€260 online and €210-€310 at the airport. You can find the actual price for your flight by using your booking reference on the Swiss website.

Overall, your hand luggage does NOT meet the dimension criteria. You haven't provided any details on your main piece of hand luggage but the backpack is much too large to be a personal item. You are only allowed one full-size piece of hand luggage and you have two.
In fact, it seems your bag pack is bigger than allowed even on its own. It's a soft bag so you might be able to fit it into a sizer but that only works if it's not full. It's sometimes possible to get away with soft bags and airlines do not always check the dimensions but it does happen.

But given that my check-in luggage already meets dimension criteria, I am wondering if airlines will charge me for additional luggage even if total weight is within limits.

Yes, you should expect additional charges to check in an extra piece of luggage. Swiss, like many other airlines, uses what's sometimes called the “piece concept”: You are allowed a specific number of items and you are not allowed to split your allowance between several bags or suitcases, even if they meet all other restrictions as a whole (weight, volume).
In general, the allowance on Swiss intercontinental flights is only one piece of hold luggage. There are some exceptions based on fare, destination, or frequent flyer status but none that seem to apply to you.
You should therefore expect to have to check in one of your pieces of hand luggage and to pay a fee for that. Swiss claims that it's cheaper if you pay the fee in advance (“online rate”) so I would recommend doing that now and not at the airport. Volunteering to check in your other piece of hand luggage and showing up at the gate with only one bag would also avoid drawing attention to your camera back pack. That's important because you really don't want to be forced to check that one in the hold.

Check this note from the Swiss website:

With very busy flights, we sometimes also ask you to check in hand baggage at the gate that conforms to the rules. Please always ensure that you take your personal electronic devices (e.g. e-cigarettes, power banks, laptops and smartphones etc.), valuables, passport and medication with you into the cabin.

Because of gate checking mentioned above many airlines are encouraging customers to check their hand luggage. I'm not sure if Swiss is one of them, but since you are already going to the luggage drop off desk you might as well ask to check in your hand luggage. This should be free of charge or course. And in this case you can bring a personal item (backpack) with you in the cabin with "personal electronic devices (e.g. e-cigarettes, power banks, laptops and smartphones etc.), valuables, passport and medication".

So you will be violating the luggage restrictions already by trying to sneak aboard 2 pieces of carry on luggage when you're allowed only 1. That's going to hopefully lead to you having to gate check that backpack, causing flight delays and angry looks from staff and other passengers.
Both weight and size restrictions are enforced. You just don't typically notice the size limit enforcement as mostly there will be no actual measuring devices, but the luggage trays, the check in counter, etc. etc. will be designed with those limits in mind and the staff are well trained to detect excesses (a few millimeters won't usually matter, but trying to sneak a surf board in without paying the surcharges isn't going to happen).
For carry on luggage there are SOME exemptions for things you can carry in addition to the allowed single piece. That's a small purse (especially for the ladies) and a reasonably sized camera bag, sometimes these days also a small laptop bag (not my giant laptop bag with wheels though, nor a massive camera case on wheels). Exactly what will pass muster will depend greatly on the airline and potentially how heavily booked the flight is. But the days of being able to sneak 2-3 huge shopping bags each weighing in at 25kg or more onto a charter flight are hopefully finally behind us.

OP can actually have two items in the cabin as long as they fit the respective (very well defined) limits.

There’s a real weird, scolding tone to this answer.
